# Why can't we browse an Azure Artifact in ADO Release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, devops

When I add a Build Artifact as an Artifact in the Release pipeline, and then if I try to use it as a source for "Package or folder" input in App Service Deploy task, it shows me the actual contents of the folder like this:

[image]

However, if I add a package from Azure Artifact which also contains the same "webapp.zip" folder published from a build pipeline to Azure Artifacts, and then try to browse it, does not show anything and I get this error/warning message "This artifact cannot be browsed." at the top:

[image]

When I use a full path like "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_webapp/webapp.zip", it deploys the zip to App Service so it' evident that zip file is there.

Then why do we get this warning and can't see it's contents?